# Move items from Outlook inbox with Powershell

Tags: email, powershell, outlook

currently i ran an script on powershell to parse the inbox and gather all the inbox matching the emails that have a category set and unread. The script is able to move the items and place on the different specified folders.

There're two group mailbox, on the one that at the end of the day items are less than 100 the script works fine, however on the other mailbox that have +200 items to be moved each end of the working day it gives an error for each message in the loop.

"The items were copied instead of moved because the original items cannot be deleted. Your server administrator has limited the number of items you can open simultaneously"

Mailbox are configured as Online mode, not cache. Is there any way to create batchs or workaround for that issue?

Answer (score 0):

The error means the current user does not have the right to delete the messages in the source folder. You need to adjust the permissions appropriately (right click on the folder, Permissions tab).